# Split a string and search a domain for each individual word with Grails and Groovy

Tags: search, grails, groovy

I'm creating a search function to browse through one of my domain classes.

I have a string which i would like to split into individual words, so that I can search through my domain class for each word.

For example, my User class has a name attribute and a biography attribute. 
If I searched **"Tom Chicago"** in my system, it would return all the users with a name like **%tom%** or with a name like **%chicago%** AND all the users with a biography containing either of those words to.

I have started my search function like this:

```
def userCriteria = User.createCriteria()
userResults = userCriteria.list(){
    like("name", "%${q}%")
    like("biography", "%${q}%")
}
```

Obviously this is not doing quite what I'd like it to do. How can I adjust it so that it does?

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin like Searchable

Comment: Have you thought of using [Elastic Search](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) on a long run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is going to create some horrible SQL statements it will do what you want. Not sure I could in good faith use this in a production system when such things as Searchable exist.

```
def userCriteria = User.createCriteria()
def userResults = userCriteria.list() {
  or {
    q.split(" ").each { t ->
      ilike("name", "%$t%")
      ilike("biography", "%$t%")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I know searchable is a much better solution than I am building but I need to do it without.